# upload_max_filesize from php.ini doesn't work

Tags: php, xampp

I want to import a database which size is 11 MB. I installed xampp local server. it was set in php.ini to 2M.
I set it to `upload_max_filesize=128M` and also `max_file_uploads=128`. After that i used the **phpinfo()** function, which show me that is set to 128 MB, BUT in phpmyadmin it shows me 8MB and i got this message after import: **You probably tried to upload a file that is too large. Please refer to documentation for a workaround for this limit.**

YES, I restarted the server many times!

I tried to find and answer from another posts but with no results. Can anyone help me with this ? thx

Comment: php.ini is ONE place the setting can be applied. check other http.conf files, .htaccess, etc... for `php_value` directives

Comment: and what should i look up in http.conf file ?

Comment: php_value, like I said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also set post max size to desired value.

```
post_max_size=128M
```

Comment: I don't have post_max_size this in php.ini. The ctrl + f didnt find it :)

Comment: well write it yourself. Just add it at the bottom of php.ini. And restart apache again.

Comment: now I get this Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit same file and import will resume. maybe you have some hint for me

Comment: adjust your values for max_execution_time and max_input_time in your php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Click on the MySQL config button (see image below) then click `my.ini` and change: `myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M` to `myisam_sort_buffer_size = 1888M`.

Increase your `M` size according to your own then click apply.

[image]